# EUREKA SPRING BOOT MICROSERVICE

Tags: java, spring-boot, debugging, netflix-eureka, spring-tool-suite

i can register with eureka but when i restart the eureka project
=> DS: Registry: lease does not exist, resource is booking: MICROSERVICE-ORDER - localhost:microservice-order:8081
My 3 services cannot re-register themselves, i already add annotation in main class (@enalble eureka..)
THANKS

[property of eureka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WrO2.png)

[property of microsevice-product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxgbv.png)

[property of microservice-order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8KFq.png)

[when i start eureka , microservice -product and order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmzDD.png)

[when i restart eureka project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhVCu.png)

i want to fix it, i don't know about it, i'm beginner

Comment: Hello, please don't post code/data/error as images. Use properly formatted text.